# How to aggregate code changes between commits

Tags: git, shell

I want to see something like an aggregated `git log --shortstat --oneline`.

Instead of the following,

```
2fd8b62 quote sending successfully
 5 files changed, 26 insertions(+), 40 deletions(-)
5bc977e Hackedup old (redundant) code so that project compiles
 14 files changed, 90 insertions(+), 80 deletions(-)
```

I want something like

```
 19 files changed, 116 insertions, 120 deletions.
```

I understand this will contain a lot of redundant data (as files changed may be common, etc.) But I want to track the work done in a day (say) or any time period.

I cannot figure out a simple way to parse the output generated by

```
git log --shortstat --oneline commit1...commit2
```

To find the total change, I can do

```
git diff --shortstat --oneline commit1...commit2
```

but I do not want this. I am considering each commit to be a valid change, even if it was partially undone in a later commit.

Comment: That's quite easy .. if you have any scripting language at hand ;) If any, what langs are acceptable? I mean, you want to just summarize the log--shortstat, right?

Comment: yes. so any commands that I can enter in my bash shell is acceptable. Actually I dont have much knowledge of shell scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/tibbon/2569089) gives a possible solution:

```
git log --shortstat  | grep "files changed" | gawk '{files+=$1; inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6} END {print "files changed", files, "lines inserted:", inserted, "lines deleted:", deleted}'
```

On multiple line, for readability:

```
git log --shortstat  | grep "files changed" | \
gawk '{files+=$1; inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6} END \ 
{print "files changed", files, "lines inserted:", inserted, "lines deleted:", deleted}'
```

---

I just tried it on the [git repo](https://github.com/git/git), for the 10 past days of commits (it works even on Windows):

```
c:\prgs\vonc\git\git>
git log --oneline --shortstat --since="10 days ago" | grep "files changed" | gawk '{files+=$1; inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6} END {print "files changed", files, "lines inserted:", inserted, "lines deleted:", deleted}'
files changed 47 lines inserted: 397 lines deleted: 30
```

---

That same technique ([using `gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)) lets you aggregate other data, like the number of commits per authors:

```
git log --pretty=format:%an | gawk '{ ++c[$0]; } END { for(cc in c) printf "%5d %s\n",c[cc],cc; }'| gsort -r

git log --pretty=format:%an | \
gawk '{ ++c[$0]; } END \
{ for(cc in c) printf "%5d %s\n",c[cc],cc; }'| gsort
```

Again, on the git repo, on Windows, it does work:

```
c:\prgs\vonc\git\git>
git log --pretty=format:%an --since="10 days ago" | gawk '{ ++c[$0]; } END { for(cc in c) printf "%5d %s\n",c[cc],cc; }'| gsort
   23 Junio C Hamano
     8 Jeff King
     3 Johannes Schindelin
```

Note that it is a bit overkill, in that it includes the merge commits.
Simpler would be

```
c:\prgs\vonc\git\git>
git shortlog -sn --no-merges --since="10 days ago"
     8  Jeff King
     6  Junio C Hamano
     3  Johannes Schindelin
```